# Convert DBNull To String Before Populating Data To Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need a way to convert DBNull to string when populating data from database to datagridview. Below is my code

```
 Private Sub FetchData()

    sql = "SELECT ContributionType,Status,PayMethod,BankName,AccountNo,Amount,FullName,District,Refno,ContributorGrp"
    sql &= " FROM tblincome WHERE TxnID=@id"

    command = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
    command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@id", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = lbltxnid.Text

    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
    dt = New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(dt)



    For Each row In dt.Rows
        PopulateGrid(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7), row(8), row(9))
    Next

    dt.Rows.Clear()
    dt.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateGrid(ContributionType As String, Status As String, PayMethod As String, BankName As String _
                         , AccountNo As String, Amount As Double, FullName As String, District As String _
                         , Refno As String, ContributorGrp As String)

    Dim row As String() = New String() {ContributionType, Status, PayMethod, BankName, AccountNo, Amount.ToString("N") _
                                       , FullName, District, Refno, ContributorGrp}
    dgvcontributions.Rows.Add(row)
End Sub
```

The fields BankName and Accountno allow for null entries so they are most likely to be the ones with null values.

Comment: What string you want to use for the null values?

Comment: Empty string ( " ") should be fine

Comment: Why don't you simply bind the `DataTable` to the grid?  Null values will be handled automatically then.  Why make things harder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this  method:

```
Public Shared Function ConvertDbVal(Of T)(obj As Object, Optional nullFallbackVal As T = Nothing) As T
    If obj Is Nothing OrElse obj.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
        Return nullFallbackVal
    Else
        Return CType(obj, T)
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim bankName As String = ConvertDbVal(row(3), "")
Dim accNumber = ConvertDbVal(row(4), "")
```

If you don't specify the (optional) fallback-value you have to specify the type explicitly:

```
Dim bankName As String = ConvertDbVal(Of String)(row(3))
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would be the best place to put the `Dim bankName = row(3).ConvertDbVal(Of String)("")`

Comment: @NickMackenzie: sorry, i hadn't tested it. You can't have extension method for `System.Object` in VB.NET (late binding issue). So i have made it a normal function.

Comment: @NickMackenzie: where you have access to the row, so before you call the method. It's better anyway to use the column-names instead of the ordinal index.